# Equations for high pass filter?

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I made my own low pass filter in matlab by taking a moving average of the signal data. But if a moving average creates a low pass filter, how exactly does one design an equation for a high pass filter? I understand the intuition regarding using an average for low pass (high frequencies will average out to zero but low frequencies will average out to a number close to the signal value).

But is there any equation used for high pass filter?

Comment: I give some examples of low and highpass filters that are more selective than simple moving average type filters here: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/basic-audio-eqs.html

Answer (score 9):

There are a lot of equations for that! Perhaps the simplest one is the one-sample delay difference function,

```
y[n] = x[n] - x[n-1]
```

or, taking its Z-transform

```
H(z) = 1 - z^-1
```

Where `H(z) = Y(z) / X(z)` is the system equation for the filter.

Using [AudioLazy](http://github.com/danilobellini/audiolazy) with MatPlotLib (Python), you can see a frequency response plot for this highpass filter by typing. (**Disclosure: I am the author of AudioLazy**)

```
from audiolazy import z
(1 - z ** -1).plot().show()
```

[image: Simple highpass filter]

You can apply it to a signal, as well

```
from audiolazy import z, Stream
filt = 1 - z ** -1
sig = Stream(1, 3, 1, -1, -3, -1) # Periodic signal
filt(sig).take(7)
```

Resulting in the first 7 samples:

```
[1.0, 2, -2, -2, -2, 2, 2]
```

The same can be done in GNU Octave (or MatLab):

```
filter([1, -1], [1], [1, 3, 1, -1, -3, -1, 1])
```

Which returns

```
[1, 2, -2, -2, -2, 2, 2]
```

That's a FIR filter in a 6-sample-periodic signal that decays from `[-3;3]` amplitude range to `[-2;2]` range in this example. If you try with a 12-sample-signal (lower frequency):

```
filt = 1 - z ** -1
sig = Stream(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -2, -1, 0)
filt(sig).take(13)
```

Now the result is another square wave, but in the `[-1;1]` range. You should try the same with sinusoids, which are meaningful for the frequency response and should keep another sinusoid as the output of the filter, with the same frequency.

You can also use a resonator at the Nyquist frequency, giving you an IIR filter. There are several other filters design that can do so (e.g. Butterworth, Chebyshev, Elliptical), for different needs. Minimum phase, linear phase, filter stability and minimizing the ripple amplitude are some possible design goals (or constraints) you can have while designing a filter.

Comment: Nice description... `diff` removes a DC baseline!

Answer (score 9):

A very simplistic high pass filter can be constructed by subtracting the low pass filter from the original data.  By subtracting the low energy content, you are left with the high energy content, thus creating a high pass filter.  Hopefully, this is intuitive.

```
data = %some data here
low_pass_data = %calc low pass here
high_pass_data = data - low_pass_data
```

Please note that @H.D. has a much more extensive answer, but thought it may be too complex for OP.

Comment: This works well if the lp filter has not delayed the signal.

Comment: @BjornRoche Exactly right, the OP mentioned using a moving average LFP filter which does not introduce a delay.

Comment: A moving average filter `(1 + z^-1 + ... + z^-(M-1))/M` needs to know both the "first half" and the "second half" of the `M` samples it's taking the average from, so we'd need a lag of `M/2` samples to make it causal and centered on whatever it's taking the average from, besides the need of delays up to `z^-(M-1)`.